# How to convert a country string to its ISO 3166-1 code using Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-locale

Does anybody know if it's possible to use Zend_Locale to get the ISO 3166-1 code for a country if you have the country name as a string?
For example I have "Nederland" so I would like to get "NL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at Zend_Locale::getTranslation(). You may get a list (a simple array) of country names - and then you may use array_search() to get the needed "country-key"!

Comment: ...and so simple the solution can be. Specially as I only allow a few countries in a few languages and so the array_search is swift. I bundled it all up in a Filter and I'm good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if Zend has something for that, but it's fairly easy to do on your own.

[This tutorial](http://dragffy.com/blog/posts/creating-a-php-array-of-iso-3166-1-country-codes) shows how you can grab the latest list of ISO 3166-1 country codes in XML format, parse it, and then create a PHP file that can be included when you need a country code translation array:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://opencountrycodes.appspot.com/xml/');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$out = '$countries'." = array(\n";
foreach ($xml->country as $country)
{
    $out .= "'{$country['code']}' => \"{$country['name']}\",\n";
}
$out .= ");";

file_put_contents('country_names.php', $out);
```

Alternately, you can save it as a CSV file and load it using PHP's [`fgetcsv()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). That would probably be preferable IMO. Or, heck, you could just save the XML and parse it when you load it.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip Lèse but indeed this part is covered by Zend_Locale. It's the conversion of the country back to the code where the country can be written in different languages that gives me a problem here.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how within Zend HTTp calls can be made, but here is probably a good resource to refer.

Use Yahoo!'s Geo data, which allows mapping of free form strings into WOE Ids. For countries, WOE Ids are the ISO 3166-1 codes.

To convert a free form string into a WOE Id, you can use the GeoPlanet APIs : http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/

Comment: Cool stuff, thank you for introducing this to me. At the moment I want to keep my code "indoors" but this is definitely going to come in handy one day.

Answer (score 2):

I have made an up-to-date collection of countrynames and ISO 3166 country codes over at:

https://github.com/johannesl/Internationalization

You can use it to convert both name => country code and reverse.

I'm also creating a collection of common country aliases that will appear on github.